# Routing Issues with Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

So, I have a User model, which is accessed by Admin::users_controller & Api::users_controller. I'm having some routing issues -  if I create a user, and then navigate to localhost:3000/admin/users, I see the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `admin_user' for #<#<Class:0x5ef0a10>:0x359ef98>
Extracted source (around line #21):
           <td><%= link_to 'Show', admin_user %></td>
```

Here's a snippet from my app\views\admin\users\index.html.erb view:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', admin_user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_admin_user_path %>
```

Here's a snippet from my controller in app\controllers\admin\users_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'my_username', password: 'my_password'
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

My rake routes output shows that I have an admin_user path

```
   admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format) admin/users#index
               POST   /admin/users(.:format) admin/users#create
new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format) admin/users#new
edit_admin_user GET   /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) admin/users#edit
    admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format) admin/users#show
               PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format) admin/users#update
               PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)
```

I know that form the _form partial, I had to iterate using the object with the correct namespace so that rails would figure out that it was a User object under the admin namespace with the code below. Is there anything similar I need to do for this iterator in index.html.erb?

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Your routing produces `admin_user_path` helper, not `admin_user`.

Comment: Changing the erb snippet from user to admin_user_path results in: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/users"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: You need to pass the `user` to the helper: `admin_user_path(user)`.